# Como leer y actualizar datos de producto en base de datos en MySQL por medio de Node.js y React.js

Tags: nodejs

La idea es tener en una base de datos de nombre Inventarios en MySQL, donde tener almacenados los datos(id, nombre, precio, imagen(dirección donde guardo la foto), stock, categoría) de las Cards de productos a vender, desde la cual por medio de una conexión que se lleva a cabo en el archivo repository.js pueda leer los datos y exportarlos para crear las Cards que se verán en la pagina web y que además se pueda actualizar el dato stock ante la reducción por compra.

Probé este código en Node.js (Funciona bien)

```
      //instalar npm i express mysql--save para que funcione.

      const express = require ('express');

      const mysql = require ('mysql');

      const app= express ();

      var connection = mysql.create Connection({

       host: "localhost",
       user: "root",
       password: "password",
       database: "inventarios",
       port: "3306",
       })

       connection.connect ((err)=>{
         if (err){
        throw err
        }else{
        console.log("Connected")
        }
        })
```

Mi problema surge en las operaciones de lectura y actualización. Para ello pensé en algo como esto pero no me surge como hacerlo:

```
        async function read() 


        async function write() 


         module.exports = {read, write,};
```

Hace poco me puse a estudiar programación web y agradecería la ayuda. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Vas por buen camino pero te falta implementar express, hasta ahora solo has establecido la conexión:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const productosModel = require("../models/productos");

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {}) ;

router.get('/agregar', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render("productos/agregar");
});
```

Te recomiendo leer la documentación de nodejs y express para continuar, una vez que entiendas la lógica de express entenderás como enviar y recibir datos.